# KendoUI Grid make specific rows unselectable

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this settings for the grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RoTechnicianAssignmentOperationModel>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .
        .
        .Selectable()
    )
```

I use this jQuery code to add disabled class to specific rows:

```
$("tr.disabledRows").addClass("k-state-disabled");
```

It only grays-out the row but it is still selectable. Is it possible to make specific rows of a Kendo Grid **unselectable**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you look on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LL3GN/658/

In it, you have an array of id we don't want to select.
On rowChange function, you need just to remove the class that make selected effect.
[line 11 to 22 fiddle js:]

```
var todeselect = new Array();
todeselect[0]='2';
todeselect[1]='3';

function checkline()
{
    var id = $('.k-state-selected td').html();
    if( jQuery.inArray(id, todeselect) >= 0 )
    {
        $('.k-state-selected').removeClass('k-state-selected k-state-selecting'); 
    }    
}
```

In the kendo grid construction, you call this function on the change event : [line 30 fiddle js]

```
change: checkline,
```

In this exemple, id is equal to 'td' because the id is in first column.

Comment: I didn't know about the `k-state-selecting` class. It did the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with newer versions of Kendo. In my case I am using an early 2019 release.

Comment: @tnk479 Could you please provide me a fiddle with this new release ? I'll try to see what I can do ...

Comment: Actually, after I wrote this comment here, I realized Telerik themselves have an example that I believe was once demonstrating selection of all rows but no longer does. I think the problem is that grid.items() used to return all rows but now does not. I think we have to get all the items through the datasource. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Selection/select-deselect-all-checkbox

Comment: So from that link you can see the problem in a telerik hosted dojo.